# Mingw g++ shows garbage output, while it runs in other IDEs and Ubuntu g++

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I have a simple C++ code, it is giving garbage values when executed in my friend's Windows 10 machine with Mingw g++. But it gives a correct output when executed in my Ubuntu(g++) and various other online compilers.

```
g++ --version
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This is the code that I am executing - https://pastebin.com/zn0aEQe1.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int v;
    cout << "\nEnter the number of vertices: ";
    cin >> v;
    int adj[v][v];
    long dist[v][v];
    int next[v][v];

    for (auto i = 0; i < v; i++)
        for (auto j = 0; j < v; j++)
            cin >> adj[i][j];

    for (auto i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                dist[i][j] = 0;
                next[i][j] = i;
            }
            else if (adj[i][j]) {
                dist[i][j] = adj[i][j];
                next[i][j] = j;
            }
            else {
                dist[i][j] = INT_MAX;
                next[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto k = 0; k < v; k++)
        for (auto i = 0; i < v; i++)
            for (auto j = 0; j < v; j++) {
                if (dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]) {
                    dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j];
                    next[i][j] = next[i][k];
                }
            }
    cout << "\nThe Shortest Distances are: \n";

    for (auto i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < v; j++) {
            cout << dist[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nThe Shortest Paths are: \n";
    // for printing path
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < v; j++) {
            int u = i, v = j;
            cout << u;
            while (u != v) {
                u = next[u][v];
                cout << "->" << u;
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I have attached the outputs from ubuntu g++(left) , Mingw g++ (black screen - right). 
Is something wrong with the code I wrote or is there some issue with mingw?

EDIT: 
The same code works in mingw g++ when I use long long for `dist` instead of long.

[image]

Comment: You wrote non-standard C++. Non-standard results shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @drescherjm, In that case, it shouldn't work even when dist is initialized with long long instead of long. But when I do that, the code works fine (so I think it is something related to overflow. And if it is so, why is it working on some compilers and not in MinGW g++- correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: `if (dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]) {` INT_MAX + INT_MAX overflows long on some platforms so if both `dist[i][k]` and `dist[k][j]` are INT_MAX you have UB. Actually INT_MAX + any positive integer will overflow on platforms where long and int are the same size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @drescherjm pointed out in the comments,`if (dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j])` was causing overflow (when used with long).

This was working for other compilers and not on the windows machine with MinGW g++ because it allocated 4 bytes for long. It worked with long long as it allocated 8 bytes for long long and hence overflow didn't occur.

When I ran the following code -

```
    int a;
    long b;
    long long c;
    a = INT_MAX;
    b = INT_MAX;
    c = INT_MAX;

    cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl<<sizeof(b)<<endl<<sizeof(c);
```

MinGW g++ gave the output as :

```
4
4
8
```

while Ubuntu g++ gave the output as:

```
4
8
8
```

The [C++ standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) says:

> There are five signed integer types : "signed char", "short int",
> "int", "long int", and "long long int". In this list, each type
> provides **at least** as much storage as those preceding it in the list.

You can read about this more over here - [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)